# How to enable the kernel menu config - HAVE_SYSCALL_TRACEPOINTS?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, lttng

I cannot find this configuration in my kernel. When I do a search, I get that the symbol exists- but unfortunately, I am not finding this option in menuconfig. Do you know is there any other name for it? how can I enable this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This configuration symbol cannot be set by a user; it is set by the architecture (in arch/*/Kconfig) if syscall tracepoints are actually implemented by that architecture.

To enable it for your architecture, you would have to write the code that handles syscall tracepoints.